# How to integrate Microsoft translator in Excel

Tags: excel, api, microsoft-translator

With Excel, the function WEBSERVICE and FILTERXML return the result of an API.
I have been able to integrate the Google API translator in Excel like this

```
=WEBSERVICE("https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?target=fr&source=en&format=text&key=myKey")
```

But I would prefer to use MSFT translator. So, I have added Translator to my Azure account but how to use the API? Language source, language destination, text, ...
Here is the API code

```
https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/
```

Comment: Do you care if the solution uses VBA?

Comment: No VBA. I just want to use the WEBSERVICE function like with the Google API